# C++ Modifying pointer in Range based for loop

Tags: c++

I tried to modify pointer of object in array like this.

```
array<unique_ptr<Object>, OBJ_SIZE> OtherList;  // All Object were allocated already.
array<Object*, OBJ_SIZE> ObjectList;

Object* GetPointerFromOtherList(int i) { return OtherList[i].get(); }

for(int i = 0; Object* obj : ObjectList)
{
     // Store pointer of pre-allocated object
     obj = GetPointerFromOtherList(i);
     i++;
}
```

But when I access to this objects, it seems like it's empty.

```
for(Object* obj : ObjectList)
{
     // Access violation because obj is null.
     obj->doSomething();
}
```

I tried other way too.

```
for(int i = 0; auto& obj : ObjectList)
{
     // store pointer of pre-allocated object.
     obj = GetPointerFromOtherList(i);
     i++;
}
```

and this work.
The `auto&` keyword is same as `Object*&`. and I don't really understand why the first method didn't worked and second one worked otherwise. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: `for (Object *obj: ObjectList)` iterates over the set of *values* of pointers contained in `ObjectList`.   Changing the values does not change the elements.   You need a reference, such as `for (Object *& obj : ObjectList)` if you want to assign to `obj`.

Comment: In the first one it’s just a pointer and you’re reassigning the *variable*, but nothing changes elsewhere. `Object*` is very different from `Object*&`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you'd had an array of `int`, you would have understood. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: you've missed the reference in your first loop: `Object*`  instead of `Object*&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Object* obj : ObjectList`, `obj` is *a copy* of the pointer element of `ObjectList`. Assigning to that copy with `obj = GetPointerFromOtherList(i);` doesn't change anything in the container, since `obj` is just a completely independent variable.

With `Object*& obj : ObjectList`, `obj` is *a reference* to the pointer element in `ObjectList`. When you assign to it with `obj = GetPointerFromOtherList(i);`, you are assigning to the pointer element inside `ObjectList`.

Comment: `auto&&` is  most  often the best element picking type in ranged `for` loops. you can optionally `const` qualify it in case of need.